# A process that keeps coming back even if I forcefully shut it down

Tags: command, taskkill, tasklist

Everyone.
I'm trying to quit the program called 'test.exe' with the following command:

```
taskkill / f / im "test.exe"
```

And I run the following command.

```
tasklist
```

but Only the pid number changes and the program runs again.
Is there a way to force this to end?